# encoding jpeg as h264 video

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I am using the following command to encode an AVI to an H264 video for use in an HTML5 video tag:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "test.avi" -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -vpre baseline -g 30 "out.mp4"
```

And this works just fine.  But I also want to create a placeholder video (long story) from a single still image, so I do this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "test.jpg" -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -vpre baseline -g 30 "out.mp4"
```

And this doesn't work. What gives?

EDIT:  After trying LordNeckbeards answer, here is my full output: http://pastebin.com/axhKpkLx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example for a 10 second output:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -i input.jpg -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune stillimage -crf 24 -vf format=yuv420p -t 10 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Same thing but with audio. The output duration will match the input audio duration:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -i input.jpg -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune stillimage -crf 24 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- `-loop 1` loops the image input.
- `-framerate` sets the frame rate of the image input. Default is 25. Some players have issues with low frame rates so a value over 6 or so is recommended.
- `-i input.jpg` the input.
- `-c:v libx264` the H.264 video encoder.
- `-preset` x264 encoding preset. Use the slowest one you can.
- `-tune` [x264 tuning](https://superuser.com/a/564404/110524) for various adjustments to fit specific situations.
- `-crf` for quality. A lower value results in higher quality. Use the highest value that still provides an acceptable quality to you. Default is 23.
- `-vf format=yuv420p` outputs the *pixel format* as `yuv420p`. This ensures the output uses a widely acceptable chroma sub-sampling scheme. Recommended for libx264 when encoding from images.
- `-c:a aac` the AAC audio encoder. If your input is already AAC or M4A then use -c:a copy instead to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) instead of re-encode.
- `-t 10` (in the first example) makes a 10 second output. Needed because the image is looping indefinitely.
- `-shortest` (in the second example) makes the output the same duration as the shortest input. In this case it is the audio since the image is looping indefinitely.
- `-movflags +faststart` relocates the moov atom to the beginning of the file after encoding is finished. Allows playback to begin faster in progressive download playing; otherwise the whole video must be downloaded before playing.
- `-profile:v main` (optional) some devices can't handle High profile.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

Comment: This is great because I couldn't even seem to get the right combination of flags to stretch out a single image to more than a single frame (I swear I tried -t... oh well).

Unfortunately it's still not appearing in my HTML5 video tag in Chrome on Mac.  I have more tests to do, but I have appended my full output after running the command in your answer above.